# manage Jenkins build status

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'd like to run batch using jenkins. And the status of build depends of number of files created in a specific folder. My question is how could I manage Jenkins build status depending of number of files created?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a shell script to count the files and return 1, if the count isn't expected.

Another way would be to use the [Text-finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) searching for a pattern in the console log.

[Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) is another alternative:

```
buildUnstable() - sets the build result to UNSTABLE.
```

If you like to use the [CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) you can use the following command:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://...:8080/ set-build-result
Sets the result of the current build. Works only if invoked from within a build.
```

Comment: Wat is the name of API that change the build status?

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the apis. The best way to do it, would be as part of the job itself with build steps.